# how to create a custom live search in WordPress from scratch

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am new in WordPress and I trying to create a live search using ajax, I want when a user presses a button a box appears, and search results show in that box.
for doing this I created a folder in my theme folder called `livesearch` in that folder I put a file called `search-live.php` and the code in that file like this:

```
<?php
//echo $_GET['search'];
$test = GetMySearchResult($_GET['search']);
print_r($test);
```

and in my `functions.php` file I create a function called `GetMySearchResult` like this:

```
function GetMySearchResult($search){
    global $wpdb;
    $myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_posts post_type = post ID LIKE %" . $search . "%" );
    
    return $myrows;
}
add_action('init', 'GetMySearchResult');
```

and I send data to `search-live.php` using ajax and code Like this:

```
<script>
        var GetSearch = document.getElementById('search');
         GetSearch.addEventListener("keyup", function(){
             //InfoData = {slug:GetSearch.value}
             $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/wp-content/themes/webranko/livesearch/search-live.php?search=' + GetSearch.value ,
                data: '',
                datatype: "html",
                success: function(result) {
                    console.log(result);
                }
            });
         });
            
         </script>
```

I already `$_GET['search'];` and everything it's ok and I can see the result in my console but when I call `GetMySearchResult($_GET['search'])` it gives me a fatal error like this:

**Fatal error**:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function GetMySearchResult() in C:\xampp\htdocs\web\wp-content\themes\webranko\livesearch\search-live.php:3
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in **C:\xampp\htdocs\web\wp-content\themes\webranko\livesearch\search-live.php** on line **3**

what I missed or what I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For creating live search just need send a GET request to `wp-json` no need to make a new query

just use this URL in ajax request:

```
<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>wp-json/wp/v2/posts?search=' + GetSearch.value
```

So ajax code should be like this:

```
<script>
        var GetSearch = document.getElementById('search');
         GetSearch.addEventListener("keyup", function(){
             //InfoData = {slug:GetSearch.value}
             $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>wp-json/wp/v2/posts?search=' + GetSearch.value ,
                data: '',
                datatype: "html",
                success: function(result) {
                    console.log(result);
                }
            });
         });
            
         </script>
```

and the HTML search input should be like this:

```
<input type="search" id="search" name="search" placeholder="search" autocomplete="off"/>
```

you must turn off the autocomplete of input

Answer (score 1):

I believe you cannot get one absolute solution as you can apply live search using many ways. But all of that should go through JavaScript. Below you can find a code snippet where I apply the live search. I know it needs so much to explain, but I hope you can read it an understand the flow of the code and therefore I can help a little bit.

The application of the below code you can find it in the search button of [this](https://ttglory.com/) website, the website is still in the development process so don't worry about the design but just press the search button. Hope I could help!

```
/*
=================================================================================
                                LIVE SEARCH
=================================================================================
*/

// VARs =======================================================================

var searchArea = $('#modal-search-input');
var spinner = `
    <div class="search_ajax_loader">
        <svg  viewBox="0 0 135 140" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <rect y="10" width="15" height="120" rx="6">
                <animate attributeName="height"
                     begin="0.5s" dur="1s"
                     values="120;110;100;90;80;70;60;50;40;140;120" calcMode="linear"
                     repeatCount="indefinite" />
                <animate attributeName="y"
                     begin="0.5s" dur="1s"
                     values="10;15;20;25;30;35;40;45;50;0;10" calcMode="linear"
                     repeatCount="indefinite" />
            </rect>
            <rect x="30" y="10" width="15" height="120" rx="6">
                <animate attributeName="height"
                     begin="0.25s" dur="1s"
                     values="120;110;100;90;80;70;60;50;40;140;120" calcMode="linear"
                     repeatCount="indefinite" />
                <animate attributeName="y"
                     begin="0.25s" dur="1s"
                     values="10;15;20;25;30;35;40;45;50;0;10" calcMode="linear"
                     repeatCount="indefinite" />
            </rect>
            <rect x="60" width="15" height="140" rx="6">
                <animate attributeName="height"
                     begin="0s" dur="1s"
                     values="120;110;100;90;80;70;60;50;40;140;120" calcMode="linear"
                     repeatCount="indefinite" />
                <animate attributeName="y"
                     begin="0s" dur="1s"
                     values="10;15;20;25;30;35;40;45;50;0;10" calcMode="linear"
                     repeatCount="indefinite" />
            </rect>
            <rect x="90" y="10" width="15" height="120" rx="6">
                <animate attributeName="height"
                     begin="0.25s" dur="1s"
                     values="120;110;100;90;80;70;60;50;40;140;120" calcMode="linear"
                     repeatCount="indefinite" />
                <animate attributeName="y"
                     begin="0.25s" dur="1s"
                     values="10;15;20;25;30;35;40;45;50;0;10" calcMode="linear"
                     repeatCount="indefinite" />
            </rect>
            <rect x="120" y="10" width="15" height="120" rx="6">
                <animate attributeName="height"
                     begin="0.5s" dur="1s"
                     values="120;110;100;90;80;70;60;50;40;140;120" calcMode="linear"
                     repeatCount="indefinite" />
                <animate attributeName="y"
                     begin="0.5s" dur="1s"
                     values="10;15;20;25;30;35;40;45;50;0;10" calcMode="linear"
                     repeatCount="indefinite" />
            </rect>
        </svg>
    </div>
`;
var isSpinnerVisible = false;
var previousValue, typingTimer;

// Excute functions ===============================================================

addSearchHTML();
SearchBtnStyle();
votEvents();




// define functions ================================================================

function addSearchHTML () {
    $('.mainmenu').append(`
        <div class="widget widget_search">
                <div id="vot_search_button"></div>
        </div>
    `);


    $('#search_modal').append(`
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">
                    <i class="rt-icon2-cross2"></i>
                </span>
            </button>
            <div class="widget widget_search">
                <div class="searchform search-form form-inline" >
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" value="" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder=" ما الذي تريد أ ن تبحث عنه؟" id="modal-search-input">
                    </div>
                    <div id="inner_search_btn"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="result_area" class="row">
                <fieldset id="result_area_sermons" class="search_column col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                    <legend class="search_legend">
                        عظات
                    </legend>
                    <ul class="search_column_result">
                        
                    </ul>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset id="result_area_tvshows" class="search_column col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                    <legend class="search_legend">
                        برامج تلفزيونية
                    </legend>
                    <ul class="search_column_result">
                        
                    </ul>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset id="result_area_articles" class="search_column col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                    <legend class="search_legend">
                        مقالات
                    </legend>
                    <ul class="search_column_result">
                        
                    </ul>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        `);

    if ($('body').hasClass('home')) {
        $('.widget_search').addClass('widget_search_homepage');
    }
}

function SearchBtnStyle () {
    var SearchBtnPadding = $('.mainmenu .menu-item > a').css('padding');
    var SearchBtnMargin = $('.mainmenu .menu-item > a').css('margin');

    $('#vot_search_button').css('padding', SearchBtnPadding);
    $('#vot_search_button').css('margin', SearchBtnMargin);
}

function votEvents (){
    $('#vot_search_button').on('click', openOverlay);
    $('#modal-search-input').on("keyup", typingLogic);
}


// event handlers functions ==========================================================

function openOverlay (){
     $('#search_modal').modal('show').find('input').first().focus();
}

function typingLogic () {
    var searchArea = $('#modal-search-input'),
    resultsDivSermons = $('#result_area #result_area_sermons .search_column_result');
    resultsDivTVshows = $('#result_area #result_area_tvshows .search_column_result');
    resultsDivArticles = $('#result_area #result_area_articles .search_column_result');

    if (searchArea.val() != previousValue) {
      clearTimeout(typingTimer);

      if (searchArea.val()) {
        if (!isSpinnerVisible) {
          resultsDivSermons.html(spinner);
          resultsDivTVshows.html(spinner);
          resultsDivArticles.html(spinner);
          isSpinnerVisible = true;
        }
        typingTimer = setTimeout(getResults, 2000);
      } else {
        resultsDivSermons.html('');
        resultsDivTVshows.html('');
        resultsDivArticles.html('');
        isSpinnerVisible = false;
      }

    }

    previousValue = searchArea.val();
}


function getResults () {
    var searchArea = $('#modal-search-input');

    //sermons
    var sermons_url = vot_vars.root_directory + '/wp-json/wp/v2/vot-sermons?search=' + searchArea.val();
    $.getJSON(sermons_url, sermons => {
      $('#result_area #result_area_sermons .search_column_result').prepend(`
            ${sermons.length ? '' : '<li>لم نستطيع العثور على عظة تطابق بحثك</li>'}
              ${sermons.map(item => `<li><a href="${item.link}">${votChangeNumbersToArabic(item.title.rendered)}</a></li>`).join('')}
            ${sermons.length ? '' : ''}
      `);
      isSpinnerVisible = false;
      $('#result_area #result_area_sermons .search_ajax_loader').hide();
    });

    //tvshows
    var tvshows_url = vot_vars.root_directory + '/wp-json/wp/v2/vot-tvshows?search=' + searchArea.val();
    $.getJSON(tvshows_url, sermons => {
      $('#result_area #result_area_tvshows .search_column_result').prepend(`
            ${sermons.length ? '' : '<li>لم نستطيع العثور على برنامج تلفزيوني يطابق بحثك</li>'}
              ${sermons.map(item => `<li><a href="${item.link}">${votChangeNumbersToArabic(item.title.rendered)}</a></li>`).join('')}
            ${sermons.length ? '' : ''}
      `);
      isSpinnerVisible = false;
      $('#result_area #result_area_tvshows .search_ajax_loader').hide();
    });

    //articles
    var articles_url = vot_vars.root_directory + '/wp-json/wp/v2/vot-articles?search=' + searchArea.val();
    $.getJSON(articles_url, sermons => {
      $('#result_area #result_area_articles .search_column_result').prepend(`
            ${sermons.length ? '' : '<li>لم نستطيع العثور على مقالة تطابق بحثك</li>'}
              ${sermons.map(item => `<li><a href="${item.link}">${votChangeNumbersToArabic(item.title.rendered)}</a></li>`).join('')}
            ${sermons.length ? '' : ''}
      `);
      isSpinnerVisible = false;
      $('#result_area #result_area_articles .search_ajax_loader').hide();
    });
}
```